# PTIJ: How can I revive my friend (if I drunkenly murder him)?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud in [Megillah](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah_7b.8) bring this incident:

> רבה ורבי זירא עבדו סעודת פורים בהדי הדדי איבסום קם רבה שחטיה לרבי זירא למחר בעי רחמי ואחייה
>
> Rabba and Rabbi Zeira prepared a Purim feast with each other, and they became intoxicated to the point that Rabba arose and slaughtered Rabbi Zeira. The next day, when he became sober and realized what he had done, Rabba asked God for mercy, and revived him.

I ask for a friend who doesn’t expect anything of this nature to arise, but if it does, how can he perform such reviving techniques - if at all?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You know, other than asking for mercy

Comment: Suggestion: don’t livestream it to Facebook.

Comment: How is this not PTIJ?

Comment: Who suggested otherwise? @DonielF

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I dunno, there’s a close vote to that effect.

Comment: @DonielF close vote is not mine, but I actually don't really see how this _is_ PTIJ. Is a Torah concept being mis-applied? Is there a distinctly Torah-style analysis? Just seems to be an arbitrary random question.

Answer (score 5):

Bava Metzi’a 84a uses the same expression בעי רחמי in the context of someone dying:

> בעו רבנן רחמי עליה ונח נפשיה
>
> The Rabbis asked for mercy for him, and he died.

So we see from here, if one wants to resurrect someone, he should kill him again.

As always, please see your local orthodox Rabbi before following any advice here. And maybe call your lawyer, too, for good measure.

Comment: And some paramedics

Comment: And maybe a travel agent.

Comment: There's actually someone (don't remember who) who holds that when it says נח נפשיה it means R' Yochanan actually calmed down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you asked this question, because there are too may people that don't know what the acronym CPR stands for. It stands for "Chassidic Purim Revival".

No, it's not a Jewish Rock group. As you know, burying the dead is called *Chessed shel Emet*. You're friend is dead, so you would be a Chassid if you buried him. Ah, but, alas, what if you're not a Chassid, and what if you think you can revive him as you claim you can. (I can't vouch for your expertise, but you can try.)

You need to call some Chassidm (who haven't gotten drunk, themselves) to make *freilach* next to your friend, and, if their Lubavitch, slap a pair of tefillin on his hand and head. Between the dancing, joy, good mood and tefillin, he should be revived pretty quickly.